# Unfold Single Method in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any keyboard shortcut in VS Code that allows us to unfold a single method and keep the other methods folded?

I am able to fold and unfold all the methods but have not been able to find a way to unfold only a single method

If able to do this, it will allow me to focus on the single method rather than being distracted by all those long lines of code

Eg below... to unfold the getTitle method and keep the other actions folded

```
import Web3 from "web3";

import Play from "../abis/Play.json";

export const WEB3_LOADED = "WEB3_LOADED";
export const WEB3_ACCOUNT_LOADED = "WEB3_ACCOUNT_LOADED";
export const TOKEN_LOADED = "TOKEN_LOADED";
export const PLAY_LOADED = "PLAY_LOADED";
export const GET_NAME = "GET_NAME";
export const SET_NAME = "SET_NAME";
export const CHANGE_TEST = "CHANGE_TEST";
export const LOAD_ALL_DATA = "LOAD_ALL_DATA";
export const TRANSFER_LOADING = "TRANSFER_LOADING";
export const TRANSFER_LOADED = "TRANSFER_LOADED";

export const loadWeb3 = (eth) => {
  const web3 = new Web3(eth);
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: WEB3_LOADED,
      connection: web3,
    });
    return web3;
  };
};

export const loadAccount = (web3) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const account = accounts[0];
    dispatch({
      type: WEB3_ACCOUNT_LOADED,
      account,
    });
  };
};

export const loadPlay = (web3, networkId) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const play = new web3.eth.Contract(
        Play.abi,
        Play.networks[networkId].address
      );
      dispatch({
        type: PLAY_LOADED,
        play,
      });
      return play;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Play Contract Not Deployed");
      return null;
    }
  };
};

export const getName = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const name = await getState().play.play.methods.name().call();
    dispatch({
      type: GET_NAME,
      name,
    });
  };
};

export const setName = (name) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      const { account } = getState().web3;
      const { play } = getState().play;
      play.methods
        .setName(name)
        .send({
          from: account,
        })
        .on("transactionHash", (hash) => {
          dispatch({
            type: SET_NAME,
            name,
          });
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
          console.error(error);
          window.alert("There was an error setting Name");
        });
    } catch (error) {
      window.alert("Failed to Set Name");
    }
  };
};

export const loadAllData = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { play } = getState().play;
    const transferStream = await play.getPastEvents("Transfer", {
      fromBlock: 0,
      toBlock: "latest",
    });
    const allTransferred = transferStream.map((event) => event.returnValues);
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_ALL_DATA,
      allTransferred,
    });
  };
};

export const subscribeToEvents = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { play } = getState().play;
    play.events.Transfer({}, (error, event) => {
      dispatch({
        type: TRANSFER_LOADED,
        payload: event.returnValues,
      });
    });
  };
};

export const transfer = (amount) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { account } = getState().web3;
    const { play } = getState().play;
    await play.methods
      .transfer(amount)
      .send({
        from: account,
      })
      .on("transactionHash", () => {
        dispatch({
          type: TRANSFER_LOADING,
        });
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        window.alert("There was an error Transferring");
      });
  };
};

export const getTitle = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const title = await getState().play.play.methods.title().call();
    console.log(title);
  };
};

export const testDemo = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log(dispatch, getState());
  };
};

export const changeTest = () => {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_TEST,
    name: "ali",
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> folds a region, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> unfolds a region as noted in the [Key Bindings Documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing):

[image: Folding]

You need to make sure your cursor is in the correct position as well.

If you want to fold/unfold *recursively*, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to fold, and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to unfold.  This will fold/unfold all regions within a region (i.e. the `getTitle()` function, and it's `return` function will get folded/unfolded respectively).

Comment: I use Cmd + K + 0 on my Mac and it folds all my methods. I can use Cmd + K + J to unfold all my methods. I tried Cmd + Option + ] however, it only unfolds part of that method. I  need to scroll down to each line and click on Cmd + Option + ] to unfold the method fully. For eg, based on your example, I need to have my cursor on getTitle then on return async and both times clicking on Cmd + Option + ] to unfold the line of codes

Comment: @HendryLim looking at [the Mac shortcuts PDF](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf),  I don't know if order matters, but the PDF states: `⌥ + ⌘ + [` folds and  `⌥ + ⌘ + ]` unfolds.  Based off your comment, you are doing  `⌘ + ⌥ + ]` / `[` respectively.  I wonder if that is throwing it off.  Besides that, I'm unsure what it could be.

Comment: thanks for sharing :) i was hoping to be able to fold all methods and then unfold the specific method I want to focus on. I suspect its something wrt the recursivity of the folding

Comment: @HendryLim, I think I see what you are saying now. I'm not sure if such a feature exists - I don't think it does unfortunately, but I'll look into it a bit more when I have time.

Comment: @HendryLim Try `Crtrl` + `K`, `Ctrl` + `[` / `]` (or the mac equivalent - I'm on a PC so I'm unsure what the keys are!).  I think this is what you are after.  [This will fold/unfold recursively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhEus.png). If I fold all the functions, then navigate to the one I want to unfold, this unfolds the entire function.  So for your `getTitle()` function, it expands the function, plus the `return` function.  If this is what you are after, I'll edit my post to include this info.

Comment: @HendryLim awesome, I'll edit my post, be sure to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

> If able to do this, it will allow me to focus on the single method rather than being distracted by all those long lines of code

Another approach, [delivered first in VSCode 1.70](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#editor-sticky-scroll), and confirmed with VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022, available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)) is **sticky scroll**.

> ### `editor.stickyScroll.enabled`
>
> Shows the nested current scopes during the scroll at the top of the editor.
>
> It is now possible to display UI showing which scope the user is in during scrolling.
> The "sticky scroll" UI will show which class/interface/namespace/function/method/constructor the top of the editor is in, helping you know the location within a document.
>
> [image: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/raw/vnext/release-notes/images/1_70/sticky-scroll.gif]

That way, you always know what you are looking at.

---

For non-supported languages, Sticky Scroll can work on indent, with [VSCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73587407/6309).

[image: Sticky Scroll based on indent]

---

And VSCode 1.77 (March 2023) adds the commands:

- `stickyScrollFocused`: Whether the sticky scroll is focused
- `stickyScrollVisible`: Whether the sticky scroll is visible

That means you can add keyboard shortcuts for those commands.
See [issue 169107](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/169107) and [PR 174670](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/174670/files).